# Web content returned differently between Obj-C and Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am grabbing the html from facebook.com in two apps, one Obj-C and the other Swift. But simulators are logged in and thus a cookie is stored and the sites show a valid account. The issue is the Swift app is returning differing html, not complete with user information. Obj-C using UIWebView, Swift using WKWebView. The code grabbing the html is independent from the web control.

If i run the Swift app from the real device, i get the correct html. I am not seeing why this is occurring. Thoughts?

Obj-C:

```
var htmlString: String = ""
let requestURL = URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")

do {
    htmlString = try String(contentsOf: requestURL!, encoding: .ascii)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Swift:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.facebook.com"];
NSError *error;
htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:requestURL
                                      encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                         error:&error];
```

Comment: Away from question but where is http/https ??

Comment: Sorry, yes, https:// for both, i was just typing that in directly for the sample rather than explaining my app's library constants.. sorry, will edit.

Comment: It's not difference between ObjC and Swift. It's difference between UIWebView and WKWebView

Comment: So something in wkwebview is hiding the logged in state of the site. The UserAgent maybe at play here?